# unfortunately Google play service has stopped error

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have flashed a custom ROM in my phone. It doesn't support Google play service as the Google play store shows this app as not compatible. 
So I installed the apk from outside. But then also I am facing an issue that some apps like YouTube when opened shows that "YouTube relies on Google play service and it is not supported in your device contact the developer" and the app closes. And the Google play services shows "unfortunately Google play services has stopped working". 
I can't clear the updates of Google play service as it gets uninstalled. So how to solve this. I want to use this ROM.

Thanks in advance....

Akhil Vijayan

Answer (score 0):

These links might help you.

1. https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27808/how-can-i-install-the-google-apps-package-play-store-on-my-android-device
2. http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2174013 did you try this ?

Comment: The problem is solved but now google play store is showing "error retrieving information from server [RH-01]. What to do?

Comment: I have done clearing the data and all of Google play but this didn't work for me